# solve the system $x' = x^2; y' = y^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do I solve the system $x' = x^2; y' = y^2$

I know this is completely decoupled. However, I forgot how to solve a system with nonlinear terms.

Could anyone get me started on this?

Comment: The individual equations are separable.

Comment: yes....however I forgot how to solve a function with a nonlinear term

Comment: Write $x'/x^2 = 1$ and integrate.

Comment: after integrating, i got $-x^{-1} = x $...what is next?

Comment: Integrate $dt$; you should find $-x^{-1} = t + c$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equations are separable; we can write

$$\frac{x'(t)}{x(t)^2} = 1$$

Integrate with respect to $t$:

$$\int \frac{x'(t)}{x(t)^2} dt = \int dt \implies -\frac{1}{x(t)} = t + c$$

for a constant $c$, to be determined from any initial conditions given. Likewise for $y$.

Comment: so the solution for x is $ \frac{-1}{t+c} $

Comment: @afsdfdfsaf Yes.

Comment: however, should not the answer have a x term in it?

Comment: @afsdfdfsaf It does: $x(t) = -1/(t + c)$.

Comment: If I am looking for the flow $\phi_t(x,y)$ will this make a different?